# how do i call a function from another class which contain my objects?

Tags: node.js, oop

i want my program to call the function in class Contact which has a method called getcontactdetails().
How do I call the method when the objects are stored in another class?
e.g.
Display should be when i call the function:
Name: Homer
Mobile Number: 98849959

```
var input = require("readline-sync");
var readline = require("readline-sync");
class Contact{
    constructor(name,mobileNumber){
        this.name=name;
        this.mobileNumber=mobileNumber;
    }
    getcontactdetails(){
        var s = 'Name: ' + this.name;
        s += "\nMobile Number: " + this.mobileNumber;
        return s;
    }
}
class AddressBook{
    constructor(){
        this.myContact = [];  //class property
        this.myContact.push(new Contact("Homer", 98849959));
        this.myContact.push(new Contact("Marge", 84774744));
        this.myContact.push(new Contact("Lisa", 86994994));
        this.myContact.push(new Contact("Maggie", 94775883));
        this.myContact.push(new Contact("Bart", 88838848));
    }
}
var myaddressBook = new AddressBook();
console.log(myaddressBook.getcontactdetails)
```

Comment: use super() to call the another class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call it by referencing the instance stored in the myContact array.

For example:

```
var myaddressBook = new AddressBook();
console.log(myaddressBook.myContact[0].getcontactdetails());
```

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in the property name, try to access the property myContact intead of myContacts